# How to workaround spaces in folder name when trying to list contents of S3 bucket in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Absolute beginner to writing scripts here. I need to pull down a list of everything that's in a particular folder inside our S3 bucket, but the folder the files are in has spaces in the name and when I ran the script in PowerShell it didn't do any thing, but when I ran it on another folder without spaces it worked. The script I'm using is:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/Folder Name/tiff/ --summarize --human-readable --recursive >> c:\Reconciliation\list.csv
```

Comment: Try wrapping the parameter in quotes, eg `aws s3 ls "s3://bucketname/Folder Name/tiff/" ...`

Answer (score 2):

When passing a path, make sure the parameter is quoted so that it is recognized as a single parameter.

Therefore, use:

```
aws s3 ls "s3://bucketname/Folder Name/tiff/" ...
```

This keeps it as one file path, rather than splitting between words.

Comment: Copied comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-), to invoke commands whose names or paths are stored in quoted strings and/or are referenced via variables.

Comment: ok, and how would that look? When I say beginner I mean almost total ignorance and I don't want to get fired if I do something wrong and delete important files or something haha